# How do you call executeFetchRequest asynchronously?

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, executefetchrequest

I am using Core Data in an IOS application and am experiencing a bottleneck while fetching data. I am calling `executeFetchRequests` multiple times in a loop to fetch 1 result each time. Each fetch takes a short time, but since I am calling it about 500 times the fetch takes at least a second. I am having trouble calling executeFetchRequest using GCD.

My code looks like this. (I removed code that saves the data, since it is not the problem).

Setup Code (I am unsure if this should go inside the threaded code, it doesn't work either way).

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    [fetchrequest setEntity:entity];
```

Setup GCD stuff

```
    dispatch_group_t x_group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_queue_t x_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Iterate through each predicate

```
    for (NSPredicate *predicate in arrayOfPredicates) {

        [fetchrequest setPredicate:predicate];    

        dispatch_group_async(x_group, x_queue, ^{

        NSError *error;

        NSArray *array  = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:&error];

        for (Entity *managedObject in array) {

            // save stuff to array inside of thread to pass to an array using locks. 

        }    
        });
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(x_group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

... more code here...
```

However this code never gets past `dispatch_group_wait` and when fetching using this method the fetched managedObject is always an empty string. How can I do this asynchronously, so that there isn't a long delay period?

Comment: `[context performBlock:^ { /* Create & execute your NSFetchRequest here */ }];` will asynchronously execute your fetch requests in a thread-safe manner. The "Concurrency with Core Data" document listed by Jeffery Thomas has more detailed info.

Comment: Why do you have to loop? Please show what you are doing - this can almost certainly be done without doing fetch requests in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is a context is not thread safe. See: [Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)

---

The longer answer is you may have the wrong approach. I would setup the code so all required objects can be fetched using a single request: even if I needed to change the schema to make that happen.

---

**Update Example of Single Predicate**

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:arrayOfPredicates];
 [fetchrequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: How could I setup the code to fetch it all in one request? I am essentially sending a predicate to search for a string using the predicate and fetch the object corresponding to it. How can I do this all at once?

Comment: [`+[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/orPredicateWithSubpredicates:) is the first thing which comes to mind.